# Ng2-pagination error

Tags: angular, pagination

i'm new to Angular2 and I want to put pagination in my application, but i'm getting this error when using ng2-pagination.

[NG2-Pagination ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqc3o.png)

I used the basic example of:
http://michaelbromley.github.io/ng2-pagination/

so I have this on my component:

```
import {ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, EventEmitter} from 'angular2/core';       
import {PaginatePipe, PaginationControlsCmp, PaginationService} from 'ng2-pagination';


@Component({

    selector: 'consultaVehicle',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/home/vehicles/consultaVehicle.html',
    providers: [VehicleService, MarcaModelsService],
    directives: [PaginationControlsCmp],
    pipes: [PaginatePipe],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
```

I already imported the bundle in the index.html:
**/dist/ng2-pagination-bundle.js"**

**Versions:**

```
"ng2-pagination": "^0.3.4",
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.0",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add 'PaginationService' as a provider
e.g.

```
providers: [PaginationService , VehicleService, MarcaModelsService],
```